# The maximal ideals in the polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $A=\Bbb C[x,y]/(xy,y(y-a))$. I want to know the maximal ideals in $A$.

I don't know how do deal with it, I'm confused by the structure of $A$.

Comment: I guess it might be helpful to see that any ideal of $A$ is of the form $J/(xy,y(y-a))$ where $J$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ containing $(xy,y(y-a))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $C=\Bbb C$, apply the Nullstellensatz.  One of its characterizations gives you a correspondence between the maximal ideals of $A$ (equivalently, maximal ideals of $\Bbb C[x,y]$ containing $(xy,y(y-a))$) and the zero set of $(xy,y(y-a))$.

Comment: I'm just a beginner so can you say it in detail?

Comment: If $I$ is an ideal of a polynomial ring over an algebraically closed field and $\mathcal Z(I)$ is the set of common zeros of $I$, then the elements of $\mathcal Z(I)$ are in bijective correspondence with the maximal ideals containing $I$.  If, for example $(1,3,i)$ was a common zero for an ideal in $\Bbb C[x,y,z]$, then it corresponds to the maximal ideal $(x-1,y-3,z-i)$.